# HTML: Making a link lead to the anchor centered in the middle of the page

Tags: html, anchor, center

I have a link to an anchor on my html page. When the link is clicked it causes the page to scroll to the anchor so that the anchor is at the very top of the visible part of the page. How can I make the page scroll so that the anchor will be in the middle of the page?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no straight way of doing this in pure html\css. It is possible though using js, by getting the element's top location and setting the page's top position to that element's position minus half of the page's height.

Answer (score 28):

I found a solution [Anchor Links With A Fixed Header](http://pixelflips.com/blog/anchor-links-with-a-fixed-header) posted by Phillip, he is a web designer. Phillip added a new EMPTY span as the anchor position.

```
<span class="anchor" id="section1"></span>
<div class="section"></div>
```

then put the following css code

```
.anchor{
  display: block;
  height: 115px; /*same height as header*/
  margin-top: -115px; /*same height as header*/
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

Thanks, Phillip!

Answer (score 18):

Place a `<span class="anchor" id="X">` then style the `anchor` class like:

```
.anchor {
  position: absolute;
  transform: translateY(-50vh);
}
```

With [`-50vh`](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_units.asp) the anchor will scroll in the middle of the screen.

Comment: This looks like a very nice and clean solution. Beware of the browser support: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_transform.asp

Comment: Brilliant answer! Not complete though: I would add "top:50%" to the .anchor class as well. And please note that anchor's parent should "relative" or "absolute" position attribute

Answer (score 11):

html:

```
<a id="anchor">NEWS</a>
```

css:

```
#anchor{
position: relative;
padding-top: 100px; //(whatever distance from the top of the page you want)
}
```

worked fine for me

Comment: Excellent! It could not be simpler.

Comment: This was the solution that worked for me. The most upvoted answer did not.

Answer (score 4):

if you want without blank space do it like this:

`<h2 id="jump_tag" style="padding-top: 500pt; margin-top: -500pt;"></h2>`

but, you'll still have to regulate height from javascript

Answer (score 3):

Extending off of [charles.cc.hsu's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29123823/8421261), we can do this for elements of arbitrary height using the `vh` CSS unit, which is relative to the viewport's height.

HTML:

```
<span class="anchor" id="section1"></span>
<div class="section"></div>
```

CSS:

```
.anchor{
    display: block;
    height: 50vh; /* 50% viewport height */
    margin-top: -50vh;
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

`vh` is supported in in IE9 and up, so it's pretty safe to use.

Answer (score 2):

Determine what part of your page you actually want at the top, and place the anchor there instead. You won't be able to change the way browsers interpret anchors - at least not without upsetting your users.

Comment: Depending on the width of the browser window and the way the page flows, this method could cause the actual anchor to be below the viewport.  I'd go with the javascript solution, recognizing that browsers without javascript will just have to deal without the fancy feature.

Answer (score 1):

Since "middle of the page" is relative to the size of the user's screen and window at any given time, you are going to have to use Javascript to achieve this, as there is no way in pure HTML/CSS to get the vertical screen width.

Comment: vertical screen width, a.k.a. screen height?

Answer (score 0):

I'd try putting a negative margin (or other positioning method) equal to half the page height on the target anchor tag.

Answer (score 0):

Firefox supports setting a padding-top property on the named anchor. From there, you could set a cookie via javascript that contains the browser's dimensions, and adjust your padding-top accordingly server-side. To the end user, it would look like its pure html/css, but noam is correct in that a wee bit of JS is needed to get the browser's dimensions, since it doesn't  give you this information without a little coercion.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(window).on("load", function () {
    var urlHash = window.location.href.split("#")[1];
    if (urlHash &&  $('#' + urlHash).length )
          $('html,body').animate({
              scrollTop: $('#' + urlHash).offset().top-100
          }, 1000);
});
```