# HTML: click on anchor tag with id should go to middle of screen

Tags: html, css

When I click on `<a href="discription.html#proprietorship">Go</a>`

it looks like:

[image: PROPRIETORSHIP heading at top]

and I want it to look like this:

[image: PROPRIETORSHIP heading in middle]

I have a lot of content for this page and I want a click on href#id to go to the middle of the screen.

I can't use `position: fixed` and `padding`.

Comment: Can you add an fiddle?

Comment: Did you try absolute position?

Comment: @insertusernamehere can u provide me javascript code for solve this problem

Comment: While it's a slight work-around, could you not just place the anchor *above* the Proprietorship box instead of inside it? The obvious solution otherwise is JavaScript as far as I'm aware.

Comment: Can you explain why you can't use `position:fixed` or padding? Are there other properties you can't use?

Comment: @MrLister i have lot of content for this page if i use "position:fixed" scroll not work. content will stay same place...

Answer (score 0):

Use an empty `span` inside that `div`

```
<div class="iAmTarget">  
  <span class="anchor" id="scrolllHere">
  </span>
</div>
```

Then move that span in center of div

```
.anchor{
  display: block;
  position:absolute;
  top:50%;
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

Read this for more info: **https://css-tricks.com/hash-tag-links-padding/**

Answer (score 0):

I got my answer

```
<h2 id="jump_tag" style="padding-top: 500pt; margin-top: -500pt;"></h2>
```

Link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38564588/6936747

@Sly_TheKing thanks